# Nominalisation and は

Tags: nuances, particle-は, nominalization

I posted a question a long time ago about why we need の in this sentence:

> 毎日、同じ物を食べる**の**は、面白くない
>
> Eating the same thing everyday is not interesting.

To which I was told that adding の here nominalises the verb and turns it into the gerund which I understood completely. However, I was just curious as to what the nuance is if you didn't have の?

> 毎日、同じ物を食べる**は**、面白くない

I think the nuance here could be interpreted as

"To eat the same thing everyday is not interesting"

But I'm really unsure.

I read in another post that you cannot put が here because が takes a noun. But I read nowhere else about having は here without the の to nominalise the verb.

Before you post about "you can nominalise the verb with の then add が ~", this is not really what I'm asking.

I just want to know what is the nuance if I just have は after the verb and no の. Is that grammatically correct? I have not seen it anywhere and I'm curious as to where and when this would be used (if it makes sense).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In "regular" Modern grammar, it would ***not*** be considered correct to say:

> 「毎日{まいにち}、同{おな}じ物{もの}を食{た}べる**は**、おもしろくない。」

You need to place the nominalizer 「の」 between 「食べる」 and 「は」.

In Classical Japanese, however, it was perfectly grammatical to place a subject marker 「は」 or 「が」 ***directly*** after a verb in its dictionary form.

Even today, you will occasionally encounter the remnant of that old usage in certain fixed expressions such as:

> 「逃{に}げる**が**勝{か}ち。」= "He who fights and runs away may live to fight another day."  A literal TL is: "To run away is to win."
>
> 「見{み}る**は**信{しん}ずるなり。」= "Seeing is believing."

If you actually used this old form (sans nominalizer) **outside of these fixed expressions** in an everyday kind of conversation today, you would sound incredibly funny.

Comment: <In Classical Japanese, however, it was more than correct to place a subject marker 「は」 or 「が」 directly after a verb in its dictionary form.>No, that is *incorrect*. As in "復讐するは我にあり", the verb preceding "は" is in "連体形".

Comment: 日本の学校文法では「連体形」を教えても、外国語としての日本語教育では「連体形」を教えないと思うんですけど・・・。活用形は 「辞書形」「ます形」「連用形」「ない形」「た形」「て形」・・・  [東京外大言語モジュール](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/modules/ja/gmod/contents/card/038.html) 　・[日本語教育能力検定試験対策](http://www.kanjifumi.jp/keyword/fu/futsutai.htm)　・　[他ページ「日本語の動詞のフォーム」](https://www.coscom.co.jp/japaneseverb/japaneseverb01-jpk.html)

Comment: @eltonjohn "nothing remotely resembling to that was found." >> 本当ですか？「見るは信ずる（なり・にあらず、等）」(quote付きで)若干ヒットしますが・・・？ -> [これ](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AF%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%82%8A&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=I7usVYvhJojc0ATy5I6QCQ#q=%22%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AF%E4%BF%A1%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8B%22&newwindow=1&filter=0) "If it is coined by the appender" >> そういうことではないようですよ？

Comment: @choco: <日本の学校文法では「連体形」を教えても、外国語としての日本語教育では「連体形」を教えない> That looks right: I made a google search and found this -> https://repository.lib.gifu-u.ac.jp/bitstream/123456789/3396/1/KJ00004246589.pdf which points out the problems concerning that tendency. I am not asserting that "連体形" should be taught at any cost, but without differentiation and just teaching "辞書形", problems will arise as pointed out in the said article. <「見るは信ずる（なり・にあらず、等）」(quote付きで)若干ヒットしますが・・・？ -> I serached again, but what I found were three items with "見る事は信ずる事なり". Or is there any magic?

Comment: 「"見るは信ずる"」っていうふうに、「" "」のダブルクオテーションマーク付けてググらはりましたか？　私がググると、こう見えますよ。>> [イメージ](https://scontent-nrt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xtf1/v/t1.0-9/11751433_773270006114218_1259585465705247391_n.jpg?oh=5a06a223101686f4dbc513802fea8a5e&oe=5616ACBE)

Comment: @choco: <「" "」のダブルクオテーションマーク付けて> Ah, that's the magic. Thanks.

Comment: Modern 終止形 is descended from classical 連体形 while the real classical 終止形 was perished long ago. The alleged 連体形 in 学校文法 is but a mnemonic expedient to learn or keep it to classical grammar, I think.