# は in front of verb without it being nominalized

Tags: particle-は, nominalization

Can は follow a verb that has not been nominalized or is this just the character's peculiar way of speaking for example:

> 美しきものは空の上、楽しげ**なるは**海の底。
>
> 私に**能うるは**世を羨みながら蒲団の壁蝨養うことのみ。

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25801/542)