# How does the pattern of ommiting の of のは work?

Tags: word-choice, anime

```
目指すは港の赤い塔
```

Sentence from the song "1/6 -out of the gravity".

```
残るは八人これでゲームは三分の一が終了した事になる
```

Sentence from episode 8 of "Mirai Nikki".

Is that something grammatically wrong that people sometimes say?

Comment: Duplicate? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25801/7810

Comment: Thank you. I posted another post with a similar content. Would you look at that?