# What is the meaning of である in 今日の晩餐は松坂牛のステーキにするである

Tags: anime

```
今日の晩餐は松坂牛のステーキにするである
```

Is this related to [Nominalisation and は](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25801/nominalisation-and-%e3%81%af) ?

If so, would that be equivalent to するのである？

This character is from Mirai Nikki episode 8 and speaks using old words like 吾輩.

He is always finishing verbal sentences with である.